# Writing from trident storm to memory grid(Apache Ignite)

Tags: apache-storm, trident

Can someone shed some light on how to write/read data from trident storm to Memory grid (Apache ignite). i googled and don't find any information/document on how to connect from trident storm to memory grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think the integration between Apache Ignite and storm should be in making sure that the data that is being streamed through Storm ends up in Apache Ignite cache. For that you should simply put the data into Ignite cache. The best way to add high volumes of data into a cache is to use `org.apache.ignite.IgniteDataLoader.addData(...)` API.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy.. How do I access the config.xml inside storm ? Storm is unable to parse the config.xml file even though all the dependency jars are available in the classpath.

Comment: If you are talking about GridGain config, then GridGain should parse it. Try setting GRIDGAIN_HOME environment variable to point to GridGain installation folder.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy.. I am starting a grid using grid = GridGain.start(configFile); where configFile = "file:///home/userid/path/grid_config.xml"; I am starting the grid witihin a bolt in the sotrm and I am facing the below issue.                                                             java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class    at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.addLog4jNoOpLogger(GridUtils.java:7697) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridGainEx.start(GridGainEx.java:494) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
org.gridgain.grid.GridGain.start(GridGain.java:314) ~[stormjar.jar:na]